# Bash scripting - loop until return value is 0

Tags: bash, shell-script, unmounting

I need to umount something in my script, but sometimes it unmount's before all of the data has finished being copied and causes the umount to fail. I looked for a way to do a "blocking" umount, but I didn't find anything. So, I tried to write a script to loop until it could be unmounted, but it doesn't work.

```
while [ `sudo umount mount` ]
do
    sleep 0.1
done
rmdir mount
```

When run outputs:

```
umount: /home/evantandersen/mount: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
rmdir: failed to remove `mount': Device or resource busy
```

Shouldn't it loop until the return value of `sudo umount mount` is 0, meaning it was successfully umounted?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `[` command is to evaluate conditional expressions. It's of no use here.

Because `umount` doesn't output anything on its standard output (the errors go to stderr), `` `sudo umount mount` `` expands to nothing.

So it's like:

```
while [ ]
do
  sleep 0.1
done
```

The `[` command, when not passed any argument beside `[` and `]` returns *false* (a non-zero exit status), so you will not enter the loop.

Even if `umount` had output its errors on stdout, using the `[` command would not have made sense, because the words resulting of that output would never have made up a valid conditional expression.

Here you want:

```
until sudo umount mount
do
  sleep 0.1
done
```

That is, you want to check the exit status of sudo/umount, not of a `[` command.

If you wanted to check if `umount` output any error or warning on its stderr, that's where the `[` could have been useful. The `-n "some-string"` is a conditional expression recognised by the `[` command to test whether `"some-string"` is empty or not, so something like:

```
while [ -n "$(sudo umount mount 2>&1 > /dev/null)" ]; do
  sleep 0.1
done
```

But looking for the presence of error or warning messages is generally a bad idea. The `umount`  command tells us whether or not it succeeds with its exit code, that's much more reliable. It could succeed and still output some warning message. It could fail and not output an error (like when it's killed).

In this particular case, note that `umount` might fail because the directory is not mounted, and you would loop forever in that case, so you could try another approach like:

```
while mountpoint -q mount && ! sudo umount mount; do
  sleep 0.1
done
```

Or if "mount" may be mounted several times and you want to unmount them all:

```
while mountpoint -q mount; do
  sudo umount mount || sleep 0.1
done
```

Comment: Works, awesome!

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference between using `[`, `[[` or not. I wish typical man pages,  GNU and/or TLDP examples about bash conditionals covered such detail

Comment: And what if it never unmounts? I think its never a good idea to have a loop without an emergency exit.

Answer (score 5):

reusable function, and will timeout in 'n' seconds

```
_umount() {
    [[ $# -lt 2 ]] && { 
        echo "Usage: ${FUNCNAME} <timeout_secs> <mnt_point>"; return 1
    }
    timeout=$(($(date +%s) + ${1}))
    until umount "${2}" 2>/dev/null || [[ $(date +%s) -gt $timeout ]]; do
       :
    done
}
```

no need to sleep

Comment: `[[...]]` is `ksh`/`bash`/`zsh` specific, all of which have the `$SECONDS` special variable, so you could do: `SECONDS=0; until umount... || ((SECONDS > $1)); do..`

Comment: Keep in mind that a `mount remount,ro` command on a mips device anno 2009 with an Intenso Micro Line USB stick can take **23** or even **30+ seconds** to complete.